# How to use attributes to affect functions in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes

According to [documentation in C# attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), It seems that in C#, the Attribute can only be served as a 
 compile-time metadata storage. You have to use reflection to manipulate it.

```
...

public class AnimalTypeAttribute : Attribute {
    // The constructor is called when the attribute is set.
    public AnimalTypeAttribute(Animal pet) {
        thePet = pet;
    }

    // Keep a variable internally ...
    protected Animal thePet;

    // .. and show a copy to the outside world.
    public Animal Pet {
        get { return thePet; }
        set { thePet = value; }
    }
}

...

class DemoClass {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        AnimalTypeTestClass testClass = new AnimalTypeTestClass();
        Type type = testClass.GetType();
        // Iterate through all the methods of the class.
        foreach(MethodInfo mInfo in type.GetMethods()) {
            // Iterate through all the Attributes for each method.
            foreach (Attribute attr in
                Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(mInfo)) {
                // Check for the AnimalType attribute.
                if (attr.GetType() == typeof(AnimalTypeAttribute))
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Method {0} has a pet {1} attribute.",
                        mInfo.Name, ((AnimalTypeAttribute)attr).Pet);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However, I have noticed that the [FlagsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), has not added any variable. Though, it has manipulated/ intercepted the output of ToString() (I guess). How does FlagsAttribute do this? How do I mimic the behavior, or affecting some functions in my custom attributes?

```
[FlagsAttribute] 
enum MultiHue : short {
   None = 0,
   Black = 1,
   Red = 2,
   Green = 4,
   Blue = 8
};

...

Console.WriteLine( "{0,3} - {1:G}", 3, (MultiHue)3); // output 3 - Black, Red
```

Comment: You do exactly what `ToString` has done, use reflection to detect the presence of your attribute and *do the right thing*. Other than a few JITter attributes and compiler attributes, the rest are just metadata and you need to write code specifically to detect and take them into account. There's no magic bullet.

Comment: (There's no magic bullet) ... built into .NET. There are AOP (aspect oriented programming) solutions, such as [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) that can decompile your assembly, weave code from the attributes into the members they're applied to and rebuild your assembly from the ground up.

Comment: @BenChan Do you have further questions?

Comment: @John Thanks for your answer. I think it would be hard to override the default behavior with Attributes, without changing the existing codes/ creating new classes/ adding delegates for pre-hook and post-hook. The PostSharp workaround is not working for me, since I am actually developing unity. I understand the situation, and trying to find the best practice for unity right now.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the code for [`Enum.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs), we can see that the [`ToString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs#L1117-L1127) method calls [`InternalFormat`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs#L168-L183):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // Returns the value in a human readable format.  For PASCAL style enums who's value maps directly the name of the field is returned.
    // For PASCAL style enums who's values do not map directly the decimal value of the field is returned.
    // For BitFlags (indicated by the Flags custom attribute): If for each bit that is set in the value there is a corresponding constant
    // (a pure power of 2), then the OR string (ie "Red, Yellow") is returned. Otherwise, if the value is zero or if you can't create a string that consists of
    // pure powers of 2 OR-ed together, you return a hex value

    // Try to see if its one of the enum values, then we return a String back else the value
    return InternalFormat((RuntimeType)GetType(), ToUInt64()) ?? ValueToString();
}

private static string InternalFormat(RuntimeType eT, ulong value)
{
    Debug.Assert(eT != null);

    // These values are sorted by value. Don't change this
    TypeValuesAndNames entry = GetCachedValuesAndNames(eT, true);

    if (!entry.IsFlag) // Not marked with Flags attribute
    {
        return Enum.GetEnumName(eT, value);
    }
    else // These are flags OR'ed together (We treat everything as unsigned types)
    {
        return InternalFlagsFormat(eT, entry, value);
    }
}
```

And `InternalFormat` calls [`GetCachedValuesAndNames`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Enum.cs#L36-L56) to access an information cache.

In this `GetCachedValuesAndNames` method, we can see that it checks if the `FlagsAttribute` is defined (`bool isFlags = enumType.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), inherit: false);`):

```
private static TypeValuesAndNames GetCachedValuesAndNames(RuntimeType enumType, bool getNames)
{
    TypeValuesAndNames entry = enumType.GenericCache as TypeValuesAndNames;

    if (entry == null || (getNames && entry.Names == null))
    {
        ulong[] values = null;
        string[] names = null;
        GetEnumValuesAndNames(
            enumType.GetTypeHandleInternal(),
            JitHelpers.GetObjectHandleOnStack(ref values),
            JitHelpers.GetObjectHandleOnStack(ref names),
            getNames);
        bool isFlags = enumType.IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), inherit: false);

        entry = new TypeValuesAndNames(isFlags, values, names);
        enumType.GenericCache = entry;
    }

    return entry;
}
```

So it does indeed use reflection to determine if the `FlagsAttribute` exists, and adjusts the `ToString` result accordingly.